# Align of textbox vertically in MVC 3 Razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having a hard time on how to align vertically the textboxes in my project so I do a lot of  changes in my css but still not getting the result that I want.

Here's my Partial View for Create and Edit:
    
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
```

And Here's my stylesheet:

```
 .display-label, 
 .editor-label 
 {
 margin: 1.0em 0 0 0;
 }

 .display-field
 .editor-field 
 {  
 margin-left:200px;
 float: left;
 width: 200px;

}
```

[Output](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/8439/textbox.jpg)

Comment: Can you show what you want to see at end?

Comment: @hadas http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-03-74-metablogapi/1805.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_30F1AF6C.png i just want my label, textbox and validation message in one row and the textbox is align vertically.

Comment: But do you want the text and the suitable textboxes will be in one row?

Comment: what text? the input type? Yes I want it in one row.

Comment: The simple way is to put each type in another div and add 'float' to each div. Ask for more help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want the text to appear in one column and the input fields in another column. all aligned.

You can try having this in your CSS:

```
.editor-label
{
 margin: 1.0em 0 0 0;
 width: 100px;
 display:block;
}
```

you can change the 100px to something smaller until it fits your needs.

```
.editor-field
{  
 margin-left:200px;
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
}
```

display:block will allocate the space regardless if it has content to fill in it. Then it might solve your problem.